# read/write vs recvfrom/sendto system calls

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am currently teaching myself 64-bit assembly on Linux. I have been using [this](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) as my system call reference. Currently, when reading or writing to a socket I used the `sys_read` and `sys_write` syscalls and everything seems to work just fine (so far).

My questions are: Is there a reason to specifically use the `sys_sendto`/`sys_recvfrom` syscalls? Am I completely wrong for using `sys_read` and `sys_write`to read/write from socket? If so could you explain?

Comment: They make sense for connectionless sockets, where you want to define the target address for each packet or receive from different source addresses. This is not really an assembly question, though. See also [man sendto](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendto.2.html)

Comment: @Jester, you should post this as an answer. Even though this looks like nothing to do with assembly.